# Ember Run Loop Clarification

Tags: ember.js

I have a service that contains a queue. Anything that injects this service can add an object to the service's queue. I need the service to asynchronously remove items from this queue, and run them. It would be nice to have a periodic function that just calls like service.processQueue(). Is this a proper use case to use the Ember Run Loop? How can I add this permanently to the Ember.RunLoop, and not just ran once?

Edit:
I noticed two methods from the documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_schedule

```
run.schedule('sync', this, function() {
  // this will be executed in the first RunLoop queue, when bindings are synced
  console.log('scheduled on sync queue');
});
```

Will run.schedule add this permanently to the Ember Run Loop?

```
function sayHi() {
  console.log('hi');
}

run(function() {
  run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
  run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
  // sayHi will only be executed once, in the afterRender queue of the RunLoop
});
```

Comment: Pls show your sample code..it would be useful for me atleast...

Comment: I do not have any code. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this service before I waste time.

Comment: @torazaburo - Okay thank you. What is the difference between scheduleOnce and schedule then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `run.schedule` does is, it schedules the callback to be run once in a certain queue. The difference to `run.scheduleOnce` is that if you pass it the same function twice, like in the documentation you showed, it'll only run the function once.

In code:

```
function sayHi() {
  console.log("hi");
}

run(function() {
  schedule('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
  schedule('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
}
// hi
// hi

run(function() {
  run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
  run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myContext, sayHi);
});
// hi
```

If you want to periodically run a certain function, what you want is a recursive function, that is, a function that calls itself in a set interval. You can do it yourself, like the [`tick` function in this Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/217f0f578697ec3439a7):

```
tick: function() {
  // ...

  Ember.run.later(this, this.tick, 1000);
},
```

Or you can use an addon such as [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/) to help you schedule it.

Comment: This is the answer, I was looking for. Thank you.